# Mounting remote folder from my linux machine to my android device?

Tags: mount

How can i mount folder from my linux machine as local folder to my android device using terminal emulator on my android device? I am using android 4.4.2 and my android device is rooted.

Answer (score 1):

As you're on Kitkat with a rooted device, there's a question (with answers) on SO matching your need: [How Can I Mount A Network Folder Into An Android Internal Folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21737016/how-can-i-mount-a-network-folder-into-an-android-internal-folder) The exact answer requires your Linux machine providing the resource via Samba:

```
mount -o username=<user>,password=<pwd>,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777 -t cifs //<NAS IP Addr>/<share name> <mount point dir>
```

E.g.

```
mount -o username=guest,password=guest,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777 -t cifs //192.168.1.254/public /storage/nas/public
```

But it would certainly also be possible with other protocols, such as NFS, if your device supports it. If that's too complicated for you, you could use an app named EasySSHFS, which is available [from the Google Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ru.nsu.bobrofon.easysshfs) as well as [via my F-Droid repo](https://android.izzysoft.de/repo/apk/ru.nsu.bobrofon.easysshfs). That way you'd need neither Samba nor NFS, as an SSH daemon usually comes with your Linux distro by default (if not, you can easily install it from its default repos). *EasySSHFS* is compatible with Android 4.0 and up.

Comment: I tried the command but i get: `mount: No such device`

Comment: And you're sure you've put the correct resource (IP address, Samba share and credentials – not the ones from the example, but the ones from your environment), and the Samba share referenced does exist and is accessible?

Comment: Yes, the credentials and the ip are correct. Maybe my android device can't mount cifs file systems.

Comment: That's a possibility: it might be lacking the required modules. In that case, maybe you give the app a try to mount using SSHFS?